# how to connect and verify domain to firebase?

Tags: firebase, dns, firebase-hosting, godaddy-api

I am trying to connect my godaddy domain to firebase [image]

these records that firebase saying to remove are already not there in my records, its a new domain
and in the above alert, it is saying `not found`

what can I do to resolve this issue?